# C++ not recognizing 3points operator

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have the following code:

```
class IConfigItem
{
public:
    virtual ~IConfigItem() {};

    virtual operator int() const { return 0; }
    virtual operator std::string () const { return std::string(); }
};

template< typename T > class ConfigItem : public IConfigItem
{
private:
    T m_value;

public:
    ConfigItem< T >(const T& valueIn = 0) : m_value(valueIn) {}

    operator T() const
    {
        return m_value;
    }
};

template< typename T, typename ...Args > std::unique_ptr< T > makeUnique(Args&& ...args)
{
    return std::unique_ptr< T >(new T(std::forward< Args >(args)...));
}
```

and I am getting the following error:

> Error 1   error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '...'

I do not get it why. Why doesn't it recognize the `...`? What am I doing wrong? I have the same code on Ubuntu, and there it is working well, now I have copied this to VS2012 and it has errors. Please someone help me.

Comment: VS2012 doesn't suppport Variadic template which is a c++11 feature. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You need VS2013 for this see Variadic templates: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx

Comment: `...` is caled an ellipsis, for future information.

Comment: Is there a way to update it? or to use c++11?

Comment: Use VS 2013. Or, if you're not building production code, you can use the CTP (Compiler Technical Preview) for VS 2012, which adds variadic template support.

Comment: Actually I am using express version, is there an express version (or free) for VS2013?

Comment: VS2013 has a free community version. http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads

Comment: yey, I've not seen it, I think it was the late hour... Thanks

Comment: Installing VS 2013 (that I have not seen it may be free too) solved the problem. @drescherjm: You may put it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need Visual Studio 2013 for this see Variadic templates in the Visual Studio c++11 features support page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx

The community version of Visual Studio 2013 is available here:
http://visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads